# Is the sentence "That is my black cat (that) you are after" an emphatic sentence?

Tags: cleft-constructions

I have been taught that that the sentence pattern "It is …… that ……"  is an **emphatic sentence**:

> ***It is*** my black cat ***(that)*** you are after.

But I wonder whether this sentence is also an emphatic sentence:

> ***That is*** my black cat ***(that)*** you are after.

If it is not an emphatic sentence, how should it be parsed?

Answer (score 4):

‘Emphatic sentence’ is not a formal grammatical term, just a loose description. It appears that in this particular case your teachers have used it as user-friendly term for what grammarians call an *It- cleft*. That kind of sentence is employed to restructure a simple sentence like ...

> You are after my black cat.

... in a manner which puts the most important point in the ’new information’ position immediately after the verb. In this case, the sentence is “cleft”—cut into two pieces:

> You are after  |  my black cat.

- The original front half,  *You are after*,  is moved to the end and subordinated as a relative clause,  *which you are after*:

  > my black cat  |  which you are after
- A new subject is introduced: the ‘dummy’ pronoun, *it*, which has no referent.

  > It ..  my black cat which you are after
- This is joined with *BE* to the original back half, which is now in the desired emphatic position.

  > It is ***my black cat*** which you are after.

Your second sentence is not a cleft. *That* is the ordinary demonstrative pronoun, acting as subject. Its referent is *black cat*.

Formally the sentence may be parsed thus:

> [<sub>subject NP</sub>**That**] [<sub>verb</sub>**is**] [<sub>complement NP</sub>**my black cat** [<sub>relative clause</sub>that you are after]].

You are correct, however, in suspecting that this represents a re-arrangement of a simpler sentence. What has been ‘cleft’ here is the NP *That black cat that you are after*; the underlying sentence is

> [<sub>subject</sub>**That black cat** [<sub>relative clause</sub>that you are after]] [<sub>verb</sub>**is**] [<sub>complement pronoun</sub>**mine**].

In order to put the emphasis on the ‘*my*-ness’ of the cat,

- We move the very heavy subject NP to the end, **leaving behind** the fairly trivial determiner which heads it,  *that*:

  > That _ is mine  |  black cat that you are after.
- *That*, now at the head of the sentence, is recast as a pronoun and acts as subject:

  > **That** is mine ...
- We rejoin the two parts by recasting the original complement pronoun  *mine*   as a possessive adjective:

  > That is **my** ...

  This puts the term the speaker wants to emphasize at the head of the complement—the ‘new information’ position—and permits it be spoken with the primary emphasis:

  > That’s **my** black cat ...